# Fatal Error in JRE

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on an application and decided to update java to java7. After doing this and setting the appropriate values to env. variables $PATH and $JAVA_HOME, I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f19addeaa34, pid=28052, tid=139748278572864
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x644a34]  get_method_id(JNIEnv_*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*, bool, Thread*)+0x84
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update: Java and JavaC:**

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_40
```

Comment: Use your distribution's package manager to run a check on the files for the Java package.

Comment: What program are you running? Does java -version work? It looks like you crashed in a JNI function. If you're running your own program, try -Xcheck:jni, or running in gdb to find the full stack trace.

Comment: I wrote a binding class that invokes a Java class. Java and javac are working fine, please see the update. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: By "binding class" do mean JNI code to call a java class from C or C++?

Comment: @Joni Yes.

I've also wrote a simple CMake script and it works fine (the executable runs OK). However, when I compile the code using a bash script and a makefile, it crashes giving the above error details

Comment: Compile and run the program in debug mode, check what parameters you pass into GetMethodId.

Comment: hm... when I initially wrote the binding class I used java-6-openjdk-amd64 and now I have updated java to java-7-oracle. The error might occur because the GetMethodID signature is different in these JDKs?

Comment: How can I check the signatures?

Comment: The signature of jni functions has not changed. Probably something else is wrong, for example the class you want to use can't be found and there is no error handling, that's why you should use a debugger.

Comment: This is not true because the same code works fine when I run the CMAKE script. It's the same source code, nothing changes and it works fine. I'm quite confused now. I used gdb to debug the executable and it crashes on the GetMethodID

Comment: Differences in the execution environment may mean that a program works fine in one run and crashes in another. Did you check that the parameters that you pass to GetMethodID are OK, no NULL pointers or anything like that?

Comment: The source code is exactly the same.
I debugged the executables (one that is made using CMake and the other  created by Makefile). I put a break before calling the GetMethodID. Here are the details:

CMake:
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401dea in JNIEnv_::GetMethodID(_jclass*, char const*, char const*) ()

Makefile:
Breakpoint 1, JNIEnv_::GetMethodID (this=0x60c9d8, clazz=0x0, name=0x401be5 "<init>", sig=0x401be1 "()V")
    at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h:894
894         return functions->GetMethodID(this,clazz,name,sig);

Comment: It seems that there is a difference between the signatures of JNI function. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `NULL` as the `clazz` parameter when you call `GetMethodID`, so the program receives a `SEGV` signal when it tries to run the method. This happens probably because the class you are using could not be found when you loaded it earlier, and you don't have error checking to detect that. So:

1. Add error checking so that you'll know if the class you want to use couldn't be loaded. If you are using the `FindClass` function, check that it doesn't return NULL.
2. The class couldn't be found probably because it wasn't on the class search path. Check if you need to set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable when running your program, or if you need to set the `java.class.path` system property when creating the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Joni. The class I am using could not be found indeed. However, this error is very strange because I compiled the same code using a shell script and in eclipse. The latter .class file worked like a charm whereas the former gave me the SEGV signal. Why is that? I repeat that it is exactly the same code, copy/paste.