# JNI fatal error when having a package

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

If I put my java files in a package (like jni/test/), I get a fatal error when executing. But if I dont put the files in a package everything work fine.

**When having a package:**

```
javac jni/test/Main.java 
javah -jni jni.test.Main
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include/linux Main.cpp 
java -Djava.library.path=. jni/test/Main

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6c1ce3c, pid=3704, tid=3060386624
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x436e3c]  get_method_id(JNIEnv_*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*, bool, Thread*) [clone .isra.106]+0x7c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/idle/workspace/JNITest/src/hs_err_pid3704.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
#
Aborted
```

**When not having a package:**

```
javac Main.java
javah -jni Main
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include/linux Main.cpp 
java -Djava.library.path=. Main

//This executes fine
```

I have 2 java classes

```
public class Animal {
    public String name = null;
    public int age = 0;
}

public class Main {    
    public native Animal nativeFoo();    

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("foo");
    }        

    public void print () {
        Animal a = nativeFoo();
        System.out.println(a.name + " " + a.age);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    (new Main()).print();
    }
}
```

The c++ part

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Main */

#ifndef _Included_Main
#define _Included_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Main
 * Method:    nativeFoo
 * Signature: ()LAnimal;
 */

//if the java file in a package
//JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_jni_test_Main_nativeFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject obxj)

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Main_nativeFoo
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The cpp file

```
#include "Main.h"
//if the java file in a package
//JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_jni_test_Main_nativeFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject obxj)

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Main_nativeFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject obxj){
    jclass animal = env->FindClass("Animal");
    jmethodID cons = env->GetMethodID(animal, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject obj = env->NewObject(animal, cons);

    jfieldID age = env->GetFieldID(animal, "age", "I");
    jfieldID name = env->GetFieldID(animal, "name", "Ljava/lang/String;");

    env->SetObjectField(obj, name, env->NewStringUTF("awww"));
    env->SetIntField(obj, age, 23);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: The .h and .c file have to be different if the Java class containing the native methods is or isn't in a package. It isn't clear from your question that you appreciate this.

Comment: Of course its different, it's generated automatically. I edited my post and put it in a comment for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, which is when `get_method_id(JNIEnv_*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*, bool, Thread*)` is called via `env->GetMethodID()`, your jclass variable `animal` is null.

The FindClass call is failing because it cannot locate the class "Animal".

Validate that your class name and package definition is correct.

See [similar question answered here with the same sigsegv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078353/fatal-error-in-jre)

Comment: That is it. I did not include the package, hahaha so silly. Thank you.